# Wireshark UI doesn't show captured packets but CLI does on macOS

Tags: macos, wireshark

I installed Wireshark 3.5.0 and 3.4.2 and both versions show the same behavior:

1. `tshark -i en0` is showing packets
2. Opening the Wireshark UI, the same interface `en0` is listed, and I see the traffic preview in the list; but after double-clicking the interface, no packet is shown.

[image]

How can I debug this behavior or what do I have to do? I remember after installing it once a year ago on the same machine, it worked and showed packets on both the UI and the CLI. I removed everything and installed it again, but no success.

I am on `macOS Bug Sur 11.4`.

Comment: I don’t have a Mac handy for testing, but I imagine this is one of two issues, both dealing with permissions. Big Sur cracked down on (following Catalina’s crack down) app permissions and sandboxing. You may need to adjust app permission in the Privacy and Security settings within System Preferences. You can also try launching the Wireshark GUI with `sudo` from the command line and see if that gets you anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

> In order to capture packets, you must install the “ChmodBPF” launch daemon. —[2.5. Installing Wireshark under macOS](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChBuildInstallOSXInstall.html)

I'd recommend using [brew](https://brew.sh) to install Wireshark on macos properly.

`brew install homebrew/cask/wireshark`